# Why does git suggest recreating the branch you are trying to merge?

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a Github repo with two branches, a dev branch and a master branch. I performed some changes on the dev branch which involved moving a few files. This means that when I issued the pull request there were merge conflicts between the two branches. Git offers the suggestion on resolving the conflict via the command line by first issuing :

```
# Update the local repo with changes made on the remote
git fetch origin
```

followed by:

```
git checkout -b dev origin/dev
```

What does the above command do? I already have a branch called dev, why do I need to re-create it? Won't the previous fetch command perform any necessary updating. I think i am missing something here.

It then says to merge the newly formed dev branch with master i.e.

```
git merge master
```

This will then allow me to walk through all the conflicting files and make appropriate changes but if the changes relate to moving the files how will this show up in the suggested changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two branches on your `origin` which are pointing to the same commit, updating one of them, say `dev`, should not cause a merge conflict with `master`.

Merge conflicts happen when both branches have changes to the same section of a file.  For instance if someone else pushed changes to `master` in the same file that you edited on `dev`, a merge conflict could occur.

**What does `git checkout -b dev origin/dev` do?**

This command creates a local branch called `dev` which points to the same commit that the remote branch `origin/dev` currently points to.  If you already have a local branch called `dev`, this command will fail with the message

```
fatal: A branch named 'dev' already exists
```

Git suggests creating this branch because it is much easier to `merge` when you have a local branch reference to use in your commands.  This also avoids you from being in a "detached HEAD state" where you're not pointing to any particular branch.

`git merge master` will attempt to merge your currently checked out branch with the master branch.  So if you have checked out the `dev` branch and there is currently a merge conflict between `master` and `dev`, you will have to resolve this conflict manually.  Git will then create a merge commit which melds the two branches.  Your `dev` (and `HEAD`) will point to this merge commit after this process.

Comment: Thankyou @zposten. That is a lot clearer. I have since realised that the files that I thought had been simply moved had also been modified hence the merge conflict.